# What is the meaning of "ITEM_ID_LIST"?

Tags: android, bundle, billing

at the code below, what is the meaning of "ITEM_ID_LIST".

I don't know what to replace this..."ITEM_ID_LIST"

```
    ArrayList skuList = new ArrayList();
    skuList.add("premiumUpgrade"); 
    skuList.add("gas");
    Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
    querySkus.putStringArrayList(“ITEM_ID_LIST”, skuList);
```

Comment: Put some more code. Define the datatype of querySkus. That way it would be easier to explain what this is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works as a string Id to identify your arraylist - "skulist". You can replace this with any name of your choice.

Comment: Thank you Shushil !!! I was trying to find some code at the inApp list of google play. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

`ITEM_ID_LIST` is the key.

When you use the method `putStringArrayList(String key, ArrayList<String> value)` it inserts an `ArrayList` value into the mapping of the `Bundle`, replacing any existing value for the given key.

In terms of hat you can replace it with. You can change it to what ever you want, as long as it is a `String`.

This should help: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html

Answer (score 0):

From Android Developer Docs:

```
void     putStringArrayList(String key, ArrayList<String> value)
Inserts an ArrayList value into the mapping of this Bundle, replacing any existing value for the given key.
```

So your "ITEM_ID_LIST" is just a key that maps to skuList in your code. You can use this key value to save and retrieve value of skuList from the Bundle